# Acumatica - Passing Dashboard Parameters as Inquiry Parameters

Tags: acumatica

We know that you can dynamically pass Dashboard parameters as filter settings when setting up a widget. But is it possible to pass these dashboard parameters dynamically as Inquiry parameters as well?

Our use case is a follows...

we have a GI that groups data together. And we want to pass the dashboard parameters to the GI so that the grouped by data updates based on these parameters. It does not work when we use the filter settings, likely because it's simply filtering on the results from the GI.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can pass only filtering parameter. You cannot change grouping condition with parameter in GI